# Watin in a webservice cannot access IE

Tags: web-services, internet-explorer, watin

I have a watin application that is within a webservice.
When i test this on my local machine it works fine however as soon as it is on the server i get this error

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I have searched and tried the suggested solutions and have had not luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: WatiN is supposed to be a client-side web testing framework. It is not designed, intended nor possible to use on a webserver.